# Port Layout View Model To Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I port my ASP.NET ecommerce application to ASP Net Core. In the my application i was using LayoutViewModel and i was filling it in the base controller (for example categories, because categories is neccessary by all view) so i could use it in _Layout.cshtml. 
How can i port this structure to ASP.NET Core or do you have any suggestion? Am i use a middleware or?

Thank you.

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(HttpContext requestContext, 
                                AsyncCallback callback, 
                                object state)
        {

            ...

            var layoutViewModel = new LayoutViewModel
            {
                Categories = Categories,

            };

            ViewBag.LayoutViewModel = layoutViewModel;
            ...

        }
    }


    public class HomeController:BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myHomeViewModel= new MyHomeViewModel{Prop="Test"};

            return View(myHomeViewModel);
        }
    }


    //In _Layout.cshtml

    @{
        var layoutViewModel = (LayoutViewModel)ViewBag.LayoutViewModel
    }
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            For Example Categories Count: @layoutViewModel.Categories.Count
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net Core , you can use [View components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to defines your logic to get data in an InvokeAsync method , and render it in your partial view .

Another option is to use `ActionFilter` . For example , if you have view model :

```
public class MainLayoutViewModel
{
    public string PageTitle { get;  set; }
}
```

Creating `ActionFilter` class :

```
public class CommonViewBagInitializerActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {

        ((Controller)context.Controller).ViewBag.MainLayoutViewModel = new MainLayoutViewModel() {
            PageTitle = "MyTitle"
    };

    }
}
```

Register the filter in `ConfigureServices` function:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new CommonViewBagInitializerActionFilter());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

And in your `_Layout.cshtml` :

```
@{
    var viewModel = (MainLayoutViewModel)ViewBag.MainLayoutViewModel;
}

<title>@viewModel.PageTitle</title>
```